# php date function with variable not printing the right month

Tags: php, date

I have a page that uses some variables for the date.

```
y for year
m for month
```

and when i try to format `m` so it prints out the name of the month and not just the 2 digit number.

My Code:

```
<?php echo date('F', $_REQUEST['m'])." ".$_REQUEST['y']; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong? For some reason it keeps printing out the current month (which is december).

Comment: where is second parameter for date function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do like:

```
echo date("F",mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1, $y));
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the timestamp as the variable to the `date` function.

Try this:

```
$time = mktime(0,0,0,$_REQUEST['m']);
echo date('F',$time) . ' ' . $_REQUEST['Y'];
```